# sam deploy Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-sam

In my node js lambda sam app, I am getting this error:
Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes"

On searching more SO posts, I get that we have to either use `individual: true` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65903666/1291122)
Or we have to exclude node_modules as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63383024/1291122)

But my issue is that I am using `template.yml`, instead of `serverless.yml` which does not support `package` attribute and I get this error:

`Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: sam-app, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Invalid template property or properties [package]`

So how do I exclude `node_modules` or use `individual: true` in my case to reduce the zip size?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the linked answers are for the Serverless Framework, and won't work with SAM.

SAM doesn't have a dedicated packaging configuration. This is a known [issue](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/308) which AWS has decided to not tackle, but rather delegate to `npm`.

There are several workarounds in the github issue, but you might want to explore using a `.npmignore` file. This is similar to `.gitignore`, and lets you specify files or file globs to ignore.

You can learn more [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/ignoring-files-from-npm-package/)